# Results for Showing Variables are Uncorrelated

Tags: statistics, correlation

I keep running into implicit assumptions re claims that continuous random variables are uncorrelated.

Specifically, I am reading that  points on the circle, i.e., the random
variables $X, Y= \pm \sqrt {1 - X^2}$ are uncorrelated, without specifying the joint of $X,Y$. We can only tell, AFAIK:

$$ E(XY) - \mu_X \mu_Y = \int xyf_{XY}(x,y) dxdy - \int xf_X(X) \int yf_Y(Y)dy =0 $$ EDIT: I only need to figure out $f_{xy}(x,y)$ and then I can find the marginals.

Is there a way of finding all joints $f_{xy} (x,y)$ that would solve above equation?

Comment: Can you post a link or quote from the source where you read this?

Comment: @kccu: Do you mean the part about the variables being uncorrelated? The ref is page 241 of Douglas Montgomery's Applied Statistics for Engineers. Or you refer to something else? I will scan and bring a source ASAP.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I don't see such a claim on page 241. Is this the 3rd edition?

Comment: Will double-check. I had written it down but dont have the book with me now. Will post details ASAP, sorry.